# How to integrate jquery Datatable in mvc without Mvc.DataTable extention

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

I'm trying to migrate the jquery DataTable integration from ASP.NET Web forms to ASP.NET MVC 5.

In ASP.NET i was using static method which was called using Ajax call from the jquery DataTable plugin.

Now using ASP.NET MVC5 the method was bound in the Controller. So i could not able to make a call to the corresponding method.

Does any one have the same situation.

Tried `[WebMethod]` attribute, `[HttpGet]`, `[HttpPost]`, static methods.

Used `@Html.Action("Methodname")` 
 and `@Html.Action("Methodname", "Controller")` in Ajax url.

Nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `@Html.Action("MethodName")` try

```
@UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(
    string routeName,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    RouteValueDictionary routeValues,
    RouteCollection routeCollection,
    RequestContext requestContext,
    bool includeImplicitMvcValues
)
```

this will return the url of the controller method. Also for your controller methods, `HttpGet` is fine. Take a look at the return object from the example https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html and shape your return object accordingly.